# Why does R add a column to my graph?

Tags: r

I'm trying learn R by graphing 3 series from some data collected in a Physics lab. I have 3 csv files:

r.csv:

```
"Voltage","Current"
2,133
4,266
6,399
8,532
10,666
```

And there are two more. I load them like this:

```
r <- read.csv("~/Desktop/r.csv")
rs <- read.csv("~/Desktop/rs.csv")
rp <- read.csv("~/Desktop/rp.csv")
```

Then, I combine them into a matrix:

```
data <- cbind(r, rs, rp)
```

When I display `data`, I get this extra column on the left which I though was just there when the matrix was displayed:

```
data
  Voltage Current Voltage Current Voltage Current
1       2     133       2     270       2    67.4
2       4     266       4     535       4   134.3
3       6     399       6     803       6   200.0
4       8     532       8    1070       8   267.0
5      10     666      10    1338      10   334.0
```

But the graph shows an extra series:

```
matplot(data, type = c("b"), pch=5, col = 1:5, xlab="Voltage (V)", ylab="Current (A)")
```

[image: plot]

Also, why is the x axis all wrong? The data points are at x = 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10, but the graph shows them at 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help(matplot)` for starters:

```
matplot(x, y, type = "p", lty = 1:5, lwd = 1, lend = par("lend"),
         pch = NULL,....
```

says:

```
x,y: vectors or matrices of data for plotting.  The number of rows
      should match.  If one of them are missing, the other is taken
      as ‘y’ and an ‘x’ vector of ‘1:n’ is used.  Missing values
      (‘NA’s) are allowed.
```

so you've only given one of x and y, so `matplot` has treated your whole matrix as `y` and a vector of `1:5` on the X axis. `matplot` isn't psychic enough to realise your matrix is a mix of X and Y numbers.

Solution is is something like:

```
 matplot(data[,1], data[,-c(1,3,5)],....etc...)
```

which gets the X coordinates from the first voltage column, and then creates the Y matrix by dropping all the voltage columns using negative indexing to leave just the current columns. `data[,c(2,4,6)]` would probably work just as well.

Note this only works because your three series have all the same X-values. If this isn't the case and you want to plot multiple lines then I reckon you should look into the `ggplot2` package...

Comment: I had read that, but I didn't really understand it. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Just one thing though: what is that `-c(..)`? Why isn't it just `c(..)`?

Comment: `-c(1,2,3)` should be the same as `c(-1,-2,-3)` (type it into R to check) but takes fewer keypresses. Indexing with negative numbers *drops* rather than *selects* items. Try `(5:12)[-c(1,3)]`.